# How to get data out of GUI Form (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am relatively new to Java and I am using IntelliJ's GUI Form wizard to create a form that uses a `main()` method to create the Form.
I can get the Form to create, and have added a listener to the submit button, but I am not sure about how to get the form values back out into the rest of the application.

Because the form uses main, I can only pass in Strings, and it doesn't return anything so I can't get a reference to the frame so I can't create a method to pass in a reference to the object to populate.

Comment: You'll have to explain where you want that data to go. The objects in the form will have various methods like `getSelectedValue()` or `getText()` to get the data, but I don't think that's what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Added a project to showcase this. [[Link here](https://github.com/rinormaloku/JFrameDataPassingExample)]

In order to get data back to the first frame we would need to use the same memory reference. 
Simplifying the explanation:

1. Imagine you have a bucket.
2. The first frame tells the second frame in what bucket to place the data.
3. The Second Frame doesn't know the data yet but knows in which bucket to place it.
4. The User adds the data and clicks Ok button.
5. The Second Frame takes the data and places them in the bucket.
6. Back in the first frame we take the data from the bucket.

In the project, the Bucket is the instance of DataObject, which is passed to the SecondForm and upon clicking its button we add the value to that bucket.

Finally, a WindowFocusListener to update the field when we get back to the first frame.

Code is self-explanatory.

With functional programming, the code can be improved further. [Checkout this branch](https://github.com/rinormaloku/JFrameDataPassingExample/tree/functional-solution) .

Answer (score 0):

> Because the form uses main, I can only pass in Strings, and it doesn't return anything so I can't get a reference to the frame so I can't create a method to pass in a reference to the object to populate

You should go back to the basics of OOP. The GUI designers really hide this from you, and it takes much refactoring to get them functionally clean.

You can create any instance of your class. And run that via `main()`

For example.

```
public class Gui {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;

    public Gui(String title) {
        frame = new JFrame(title);
    }

    public void run() {
        // display Frame, add panels, etc
    }

    public String getDataFromGui() {
        return textField.getText(); // for example
    }

    // other methods

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gui g = new Gui("Hello World!");
        g.run();
    }

}
```